# Install Openbox on Tiny Core Linux (core ISO)

Tags: openbox, tinycore

How do I install Openbox on Tiny Core Linux (core ISO)?

I tried:

```
tce-load -wi openbox
```

Installation finished without errors. Then I did:

```
tce-run openbox
```

But then I got this error:

```
Openbox-Message: Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY enviroment variable.
```

Maybe I must install X first or something else?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe I must install X first or something else?

I'm not familiar with tiny core, but I'd hope it would not let you install openbox unless X were there already, since a window manager is useless without the X server.  If you've seen any GUI on it at all, methinks you have X installed.

In that case, the problem is probably that you don't have X running ;). Generally, to get it to start a particular window manager, you need create a `$HOME/.xinitrc` or `$HOME/.Xclients`...hopefully tiny core follows this pattern.  Have a look at my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83511/starting-qt-application-on-startup-for-embedded-linux/83513#83513) from yesterday and replace `myGUIapp` with `openbox` in the example Xclients file.  The point of that file it is the last of a series the X server runs at start-up.  Unfortunately, where that file should be and what it should be called may vary, but I mention the most common places in that answer.

Comment: I don't have X indeed; the core ISO doesn't have that. Is installing X just creating these directories?

Comment: @Jop: No, the X server is the core of the linux GUI; it's a fairly substantial package.  Window managers like openbox are just a layer on top of X. When skimming that wikipedia article I mistook "fltk" for "lxde", but "flwm" (the window manager on tiny core that uses fltk) is stil an Xorg client.  So X is available for tiny core, and you need it to run openbox.  If you google "tiny core Xorg openbox" you'll find some stuff; just try installing X tho, it might be that easy.

Comment: Thanks, I found this: http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:using_xorg_over_xvesa But now when executing the `startx` command, the screen turns black, and a few seconds later it returns to the commandline.