# Printing to the terminal after boot

Tags: command-line, x11, matchbox

I am attempting to start a script that echos to the terminal once matchbox-terminal is loaded. I am able to run the script if I execute it in the existing xsession script located in `/usr/bin/x-session-manager`, but I cannot see the output reflected in the terminal . My environment setup is identical to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83511/starting-qt-application-on-startup-for-embedded-linux). The last two lines in the xsessionmanager are as follows:

```
matchbox-terminal& 
exec matchbox-window-manager
```

It launches the matchbox terminal in the background and then invokes a window manager. How do I print to the terminal once it is finished booting?